# Which item should I use instead of Miracle Berry in Pokemon Stadium 2 Little cup?

Tags: pokemon-gold-silver-crystal, pokemon-stadium-2

A Miracle Berry is hard to obtain as it is based on pure luck. Could I use another Berry, or is it truly necessary?

My team uses these items already:
Goldberry, Thick club, Berry, Berryjuice, Leftovers.

And the Pokemon in question would be an Elekid with Icepunch, Thunderbolt, Cross chop, Psychic.

I could use a Magnet to further boost the electric power, or Nevermeltice to give Ice Punch more potential. Or I could use a Mint Berry to avoid sleep.

Is the Miracle Berry just too good in little cup, therefore making it worth getting it?

I probably will have use for it again in the higher cups, but before I waste my time I wanted to ask if it's replaceable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No item is necessary in Pokemon Stadium 2. In fact, you can use a team with no items - all the rental Pokemon do not use items, and at least all of R1 has been cleared using only rental Pokemon.

Miracle Berry cures any sleep. This makes it better than any other status berry such as Mint Berry in most scenarios.

I don't recall status being particularly common in Little Cup. Excluding those you have mentioned, the choice of another item is opinion based. My two recommendations are a matter of consistency vs "low chance, high reward":

- Magnet. If you're going to use a type-boosting item, using the one of the same type as your STAB is generally optimal. This is my preferred choice. It's only a small boost though
- Focus Band. This gives a small chance to avoid a KO. Only a small chance, but that chance can potentially give you an extra attack that can change the match outcome.

Comment: oh, i meant Psychic indeed. My thought behind nevermeltice would be, that thunderbolt with STAB should be enough to 1HKO every Pokemon where it's super effective, so magnet doesn't help, but to combat ground pokemon who have earthquake, icepunch has to faint them or we lose. But focus band could be great.